# Arduino UNO - Ayuda con Servomotor DS04-NFC

Tags: arduino

Me encuentro con el siguiente problema:

Estoy intentando hacer girar un servomotor DS04-NFC al pulsar un pulsador.

Al pulsar una vez quiero que gire durante cierto tiempo (5 seg, por ejemplo)
Al mantener apretado el pulsador que gire hasta que lo suelte.

Esto lo logre sin inconvenientes. El problema viene si mantengo apretado el pulsador durante un tiempo menor al que debe girar cuando pulso una vez. Es decir, si tengo programado que al "hacer un click" sobre el pulsador el servo debe girar durante 5 segundos, si yo mantengo apretado durante un tiempo menor a estos 5 segundos, el servo gira hasta completar el tiempo (debiendo frenar al soltar el pulsador).

Les dejo el código:

```css
#include <Servo.h>

const int pinBoton = 4;
Servo servo;
int estadoActual = 0;
int estadoAnterior = 0;
unsigned long tiempoDeGiro = 5000;
unsigned long tiempoQueSePresionoElBoton;


void setup() {
  pinMode(pinBoton, INPUT);
  servo.attach(12);
  Serial.begin(9600);
}

void loop() {
  estadoActual = digitalRead(pinBoton);

  if (estadoActual) { //Si el pulsador esta pulsado
    tiempoQueSePresionoElBoton = millis();  //Me guardo el momento el tiempo en el que pulsador se pulso

    if (estadoActual == estadoAnterior) { //Si antes estaba pulsado y ahora se mantiene pulsado gira continuamente
      servo.write(180);
    } else {
      unsigned long tiempoAuxiliar = millis(); //Me guardo el momento de tiempo para llegar al tiempo de giro

      while (tiempoAuxiliar < (tiempoQueSePresionoElBoton + tiempoDeGiro)) { //Si el tiempo de giro sumado al tiempo en que se presiono el boton es menor al tiempo actual gira
        servo.write(180);
        tiempoAuxiliar = millis();
      }
      
      servo.write(90);

    }

    estadoAnterior = estadoActual; //actualizo el estado anterior

  } else {
    estadoAnterior = estadoActual;
    servo.write(90);
  }

}
```

Saludos y desde ya, muchas gracias

Comment: Hola!, a ver si entendi bien, cuando apretas el boton una vez solamente tiene que girar 5 segundos, pero si mantenes apretado tiene que girar hasta que soltes, no importa el tiempo ?

Comment: Exacto! Pero lo que sucede es que si mantengo apretado menos de 5 segundos (por ejemplo 3 segundos), al soltar sigue girando durante 2 segundos

Comment: Bien, tengo una duda mas, el servo esta trucado? tengo entendido que todos los servo motores no pueden realizar giros de 360 grados, por lo que veo, nunca incrementas gradualmente los grados del servo, unicamente le decis que vaya a una posicion fija

Comment: No, así como me lo dieron de la tienda es como lo uso.
Estos modelos giran hacia un lado u otro constantemente al ingresarle '0 o '180, y se frenan cuando ingresas '90.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Aca tengo una posible solucion, no estoy 100% segudo de que funcione por que hace muchisimo no utilizo un arduino y tampoco tengo uno para testear el codigo.
Por lo tanto, deberas probarlo y lo vamos arreglando a medida que vas encontrando fallas.

```
#include <Servo.h>

const int pinBoton = 4;
Servo servo;
int estadoActual = 0;
int estadoAnterior = 0;
unsigned long tiempoDeGiro = 5000;
unsigned long tiempoQueSePresionoElBoton;
unsigned long presionoBoton = 0;
unsigned long soltoBoton = 0;

void setup() {
  pinMode(pinBoton, INPUT);
  servo.attach(12);
  Serial.begin(9600);
}

void loop() {
  estadoActual = digitalRead(pinBoton);

  if(estadoActual && !estadoAnterior){
      //guardo el primer tiempo
      presionoBoton = milis();
  }

    if(estadoActual){
        //Giro mientras esta pulsado
        servo.write(180);
    }
    else if(!estadoActual && estadoAnterior){
        // guardo el ultimo tiempo
        soltoBoton = milis();
        if(soltoBoton - presionoBoton < 100){
            //Detecto si unicamente fue una presionada o mantubo por X tiempo presionando el boton
            //Si entra aca, es por que solo presiono
            while(millis() <= (soltoBoton + tiempoDeGiro){
                //giro 5 segundos
                servo.write(180);
            }
        }
      servo.write(90); //vuelvo a la posicion inicial
    }
    estadoAnterior = estadoActual; //Actualizo el estado anterior
}
```

EDIT:
No sabria exactamente cuanto es el tiempo de en que se cumple una presionada de boton, yo puse 100 como un numero bajo, pero deberias ir probando por que capaz solo en presionar el boton se demora por ejemplo 400ms
Esto hablando para la siguiente linea

```
if(soltoBoton - presionoBoton < 100)
```

Comment: Lo pruebo, vario el valor y te comento.
Desde ya muchas gracias!

Comment: Funciono perfecto, incluso variandole el tiempo de giro. Muchas gracias por la ayuda!!!

Comment: De nada! , me alegro que haya servido :D